# Why Pythagorean triple leg differences have only certain values.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, pythagorean-triples

A variation of Euclid's formula seems to reveal why primitive Pythagorean triple leg differences appear to be restricted to the number $\,1,\,$ to selected primes raised to any integer power, or to  products of those primes, . Is my logic sound in the reasoning below?

\begin{align*}
&A=(2n-1+k)^2-k^2&&=(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k\\ 
&B=2(2n-1+k)k    &&=\phantom{(2n-1)^2+{}} 2(2n-1)k+2k^2\\ 
&C=(2n-1+k)^2+k^2 &&=(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k+2k^2
\end{align*}

$$B-A=\pm (j^2-2k^2),\,\, j=(2n-1), k,n\in\mathbb{N}$$

$$j^2\in\big\{1,9,25,49,81,\cdots\big\}\qquad 
2k^2\in\big\{2,8,18,32,50,\cdots\big\}$$

\begin{align*}
(2n-1)^2\equiv\pm 1\pmod8\\
\,\land\quad 2k^2\equiv 0,4\pmod8\\
\implies (2n-1)^2-2k^2\equiv \pm1\pmod8
\end{align*}

$$\text{We are given that }\quad GCD(j,k)=1\quad
\text{which reduces the number of (j,k) commbinatons.}$$

$$\therefore \big\vert(B-A)\big\vert
\in\big\{1,7, 17, 23, 31, 41, 47, 49
,\cdots\big\}\equiv \pm 1\pmod 8$$

$\textbf{Update: }$ A comment from Keith Backman allowed me to insert the arguments just before the conclusion above. Is the logic complete now or does it need more proof?

Comment: Why do you insist on that parametrization, when you know that everyone else uses $(2mn,m^2-n^2,m^2+n^2)$?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Using Euclid’s formula as usually expressed did not reveal this pattern to me. So, I used a version of the formula that generates only and all triples where $GCD(A,B,C)=(2x-1)^2, x\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: $m^2-2mn-n^2=u^2-2v^2$ with $u=m-n$, $v=n$. So it reduces to a question of representation by the quadratic form $u^2-2v^2$. For primitive triples, we need $u$ odd, $\gcd(u,v)=1$.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson It is not so easy to see that $\,u\,$ is an odd number greater than $\,1\,$ but it stands out in the formula I created in $\,2009\,$ to eliminate trivial triples.

Now, given my formula, is my logic sound or not?

Comment: Well, you have shown that $|B-A|\equiv\pm1\pmod8$, but I don't think you have shown that every prime $p\equiv\pm1\pmod8$ shows up as $|B-A|$, and I don't think you have shown that every prime $p$ dividing $B-A$ must satisfy $p\equiv\pm1\pmod8$.

Comment: All odd squares are $\equiv 1 \bmod 8$. All even squares are $\equiv 0,4 \bmod 8$, so twice all squares (odd or even) are $\equiv 0,2 \bmod 8$. Hence the difference between any odd square and twice any square is $\equiv \pm 1 \bmod 8$. This is true whether or not the numbers represent legs of a Pythagorean triple.

Comment: Proving it's $\pm1\pmod8$ doesn't tell you why it can't be, say, $15$.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson There can be no  $\,j^2-2k^2=15\,$ because $\,GCD(j,k)=1,\,$ as noted.

Comment: Are you suggesting that $j^2-2k^2=15$ has a solution with $\gcd(j,k)\ne1$?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson No, I’m suggesting that there is no "acceptable" solution for 
$\,j^2-2k^2\,$ where $\,GCD(j,k)\ne 1.\quad$ In the beginning, I suggested that solutions must be
[  Numbers whose prime factors are all congruent to +1 or -1 modulo 8](https://oeis.org/A058529) 
so $\,|B-A|=15=(1\cdot3\cdot5)\,$ cannot be true.

Comment: Yes, you suggested that, and then you asked whether your logic was sound. I took that to mean you were asking whether your logic was a sound proof of your suggestion, and I am pointing out that your logic doesn't prove that every prime $p\equiv\pm1\pmod8$ shows up, and doesn't prove that every prime dividing $B-A$ must satisfy $p\equiv\pm1\pmod8$. And there is no solution, acceptable or otherwise, for $j^2-2k^2=15$, whether or not you insist on $\gcd(j,k)=1$.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson  I can accept that I may not have proven much because I am just a math hobbyist. If you could provide the proof I seek in an answer, you would certainly get my checkmark. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm hoping to produce proofs of a couple of facts closely related to the topic of this question:

1. If $p$ is an odd prime dividing $u^2-2v^2$ with $\gcd(u,v)=1$, then $p\equiv\pm1\pmod8$.
2. If $p\equiv\pm1\pmod8$ is prime, then there exist integers $u,v$ such that $u^2-2v^2=p$.

This may take me a while, but the impatient reader should be able to find proofs in various introductory Number Theory textbooks, as well as on any number of websites.

Proof of 1. Let $p$ be an odd prime dividing $u^2-2v^2$ with $\gcd(u,v)=1$, so $u^2-2v^2\equiv0\pmod p$. If $p$ divides $v$, then it also divides $u$, contradiction, hence, $v$ is invertible modulo $p$, and we have $(uv^{-1})^2\equiv2\pmod p$, so $2$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$. By the Second Supplement to the Law of Quadratic Reciprocity, this implies $p\equiv\pm1\pmod8$.

Now it may be objected that the Second Supplement to the Law of Quadratic Reciprocity, while quite well-known, and covered in every Number Theory textbook that does quadratic reciprocity, is not an obvious or immediate or intuitive result, so it should be proved here. I may get around to that, but for the time being I'll take it as read. Instead, let's make a brief diversion to show that $u^2-2v^2=15$ is impossible.

From $u^2-2v^2=15$ we derive $u^2-2v^2\equiv0\pmod3$. Now $2$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $3$, and you don't need the Second Supplement to see this, you just need to calculate $a^2\pmod3$ for $a=0,1,2$ to see that you never get $2$. So, the congruence has no solution with $v$ invertible modulo $3$. On the other hand, if $3$ divides $v$, then also $3$ divides $u^2$, so $3$ divides $u$, so $9$ divides $u^2-2v^2$, so $9$ divides $15$, contradiction. Hence, $u^2-2v^2=15$ is impossible.

For the proof of 2., I refer the reader to the answer by user Pablo at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/197918/what-is-known-about-primes-of-the-form-x2-2y2